# htaccess: redirect of index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Sorry for not-very-clear title.

I'm using FatFreeFramework with his .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
    RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html?$
    #RewriteRule \.html?$ - [R=404]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Now, restyling an old site, I have in Google some url codified like

```
www.example.com/index.php?ID=12
```

I would strip away that and redirect them to home page.

I don't know how write the rule, I did try to edit in this mode but without luck:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    Redirect 301 /index.php?ID=$1 index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right above this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?ID=[0-9]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

You can't match against the query string using mod_alias's `Redirect` directive.